# Libreoffice Calc copying rows containing a specific value in column A

Tags: libreoffice

Using Libreoffice Calc I need to select and copy (or just select and I will manually copy it) from sheet1 to sheet2 just the rows containing in the column A the value 0

May you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

1. In the same spreadsheet go to first completly empty column (ex. If you use A,B,C,D - go to E)
2. In first row (ex. E1) write: =IF(A1=0;A1;"")
3. Pull lower right corner of this cell and spread it down and right.
4. Copy it and paste to sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

1. Select column A and replace all 0 values (ctrl + f, more options, active selection only) of column A with a specific value not present anywhere else, i.e &A&
2. Select all cells (Ctrl A)
3. Menu Data/Filter, auto filter
4. Select &A& in the filter list of the column
5. Copy/paste all content in a new sheet
6. replace &A& by 0 in all the new sheet

You're done